# How does CAKE get burnt since all the burn functions are internal in the source code

Tags: tokens, bsc, pancakeswap

I am trying to study CAKE of Pancakeswap source code. I don't seem to grasp how does the owner or users burn the tokens(CAKE) since all burn functions in the [source](https://bscscan.com/address/0x0e09fabb73bd3ade0a17ecc321fd13a19e81ce82#code) code are internal functions. on of the them:

```
function _burnFrom(address account, uint256 amount) internal {
        _burn(account, amount);
        _approve(
            account,
            _msgSender(),
            _allowances[account][_msgSender()].sub(amount, 'BEP20: burn amount exceeds allowance')
        );
    }
```

The entire source code can be found here : [Cake source code](https://bscscan.com/address/0x0e09fabb73bd3ade0a17ecc321fd13a19e81ce82#code)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the burn function is used. Pancakeswap does it by sending tokens to burn address which is `0x000000000000000000000000000000000000dead`